PySide6 GUI crash after sometime
I developed a PySide6 GUI for a touch screen device. After the GUI launches in fullscreen, after some time, it gets stuck and shows errors. -
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch update to same window QWidgetWindow(0x12c82a80, name="MainWindow2Window") not QWidgetWindow(0x172d03f0, name="QComboBoxPrivateContainerClassWindow")
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch release to same window QWidgetWindow(0x12c82a80, name="MainWindow2Window") not QWidgetWindow(0x172d03f0, name="QComboBoxPrivateContainerClassWindow")
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch update to same window QWidgetWindow(0x172d03f0, name="QComboBoxPrivateContainerClassWindow") not QWidgetWindow(0x12c82a80, name="MainWindow2Window")
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch update to same window QWidgetWindow(0x12c82a80, name="MainWindow2Window") not QWidgetWindow(0x172d03f0, name="QComboBoxPrivateContainerClassWindow")
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch update to same window QWidgetWindow(0x12c82a80, name="MainWindow2Window") not QWidgetWindow(0x172d03f0, name="QComboBoxPrivateContainerClassWindow")
qt.pointer.dispatch: delivering touch update to same window QWidgetWindow(0x12c82a80, name="MainWindow2Window") not QWidgetWindow(0x172d03f0, name="QComboBoxPrivateContainerClassWindow")
I tried upgrading the Pyside6 then also this issue was coming .

Does anyone know how to solve this error, it is occurring only after sometime of software use.
